# How to change default branch name for Azure DevOps host Git Repo

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

Unlike many organizations, our company use product's name as main/default branch. For now, it's still **master**  by default when we create a new Git Repo in Azure DevOps.

We have noticed this is available in GitHub--[Renaming the default branch from master](https://github.com/github/renaming).

> Many communities, both on GitHub and in the wider Git community, are
> considering renaming the default branch name of their repository from
> master. GitHub is gradually renaming the default branch of our own
> repositories from master to main.

How could we do the same thing in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could choice any name of initial branches at present.

Beginning with sprint 176’s deployment, folks with Edit policies at the project level may choose the name of the initial branch for new repositories in that project. The setting won’t change anything for existing, populated repositories.
[image]

**It will change the first branch created when you click New repository or when you initialize an empty repository.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Please check this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-repos-default-branch-name/). You must go to repository settings and change accordingly to your preferences.

[image]

Comment: Just to start, I wasn't the one to downvote you.  Some of this you might already know from being on SO, but for some [Asking reasons for downvote in comments is non-constructive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive), so don't be surprised if even your comment is removed.  My guess would be that your answer was short enough to end up in the lower quality answer queue.  Someone from there probably read it as a link-only answer and besides voting to delete also gifted you a downvote.

Comment: @Matt thank you for this. I weren't aware that length is a criteria for putting a reply in that queue. Thus I'm even happy that I got this downvote as I learnt sth and for the future I will try to add additional content to avoid such risk!